# passing parameter with map function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Stating with

```
a = ['abc', 'efg', 'hij']
```

I want to get

```
a = ['abc!', 'efg!', 'hij!']
```

But obviously without the use of `for elements in a:`...because it is not cleaver and I want to understand more about the `map` function and how it passes parameters.

So I try to append a `'!'` to all elements of the lists using the map function. But before doing so, `append` is a `list` method but not a `str` method.

```
b = map(list,a) # gives : a = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['h','i','j']]
a = map(list.append(['!']), b)
```

That last map function returns a TypeError:

```
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

I wish to know if it is possible to pass parameter to the method used by `map`. 
Thank.

Comment: You would need to incorporate a lamba but  you should not use map for side effects and it will be slower than a regular loop, not sure why you think *But obviously without the use of for elements in a:...because it is not clever * as using map as you are is much worse an idea

Comment: I wanted to avoid people answering with a loop function. That's it.

Comment: I also think my question is related to "Understanding map function" but it is more specific. It isn't really a duplicate.

Thanks for helping around :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the expected result with following code:

```
a = ['abc', 'efg', 'hij']
map(lambda x: x + '!', a) # ['abc!', 'efg!', 'hij!']
```

First parameter of [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) is a function that is applied to all items on `iterable` which is the second parameter. You can't directly pass a parameter to the function given to `map` but you can create another function (or `lambda`) that passes the parameter just like in the example above.

Typically [`list comprehension`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map) should be favored over `map` because it more obvious what you are doing:

```
[x + '!' for x in a] # ['abc!', 'efg!', 'hij!']
```

Comment: It would be great if the down voters would comment the problems so that the response could be improved.

Comment: Thank niemmi. your answer is great.

Answer (score 1):

`map` receives two parameters, a function and a list.

It calls the function once for each of the items, with the current item as a parameter.

Converting the strings into lists and appending to them might not be the best choice, due to what `map` returns, but you can actually append to strings together using the `+` operator.

You can achieve what you want by doing the following:

```
map(lambda s: s + '!', a)  # => ['abc!', 'efg!', 'hij!']
```

`lambda` is just another syntax for a function, its parameter is named s, and it returns `s + '!'`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `list comprehension`:

```
>>> a = ['abc', 'efg', 'hij']
>>> ["{}!".format(x) for x in a]
['abc!', 'efg!', 'hij!']
```

How map works

> > map(function, iterator)

it takes element on by one and applies specified function to the each element

Example:

```
>>> def add_str(x):
...     return x+"!"
...
>>> a
['abc', 'efg', 'hij']
>>> map(add_str, a)
['abc!', 'efg!', 'hij!']
```

Comment: Except they stated they didn't want to use list comprehension and learn the map function.